# is there a way to use the index numbers to select columns when doing pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am using groupby to do a sum of groups. The code I am working on looks like this:

```
data1=data.groupby('a')['b_1','b_2'].mean().reset_index()
```

However, I have more than 30 columns need to be calculated, which is from 'b_1' to 'b_30', I dont want to list all the names of columns, so I tried using index numbers of the dataset. like this:

```
data1=data.groupby('a')[list(range(3,33))].mean().reset_index()
```

But I always got: `KeyError: 'Columns not found'`
So I just wonder is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data.filter(like='b_').groupby(data['a']).mean().reset_index()
```

Or you can manually create the list of columns:

```
cols = ['b_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,33)]
data1=data.groupby('a')[cols].mean().reset_index()
```